# Conversion by substitution method

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make an conversion app for android, it's a homework. I have problems at implementing the algoritm, my application crash when the fuction is called.

**This is my Convertion class :**

```
public class Conversion {

private Double transform(Double number, Double base) {
    Double converted = (number / base) * 10 + (number % base);
    return converted;
}

public String substitution(String number, String base) {
    Double temp_number = Double.parseDouble(number);
    Double converted_number = 0.0;
    Double i = 0.0;
    while (temp_number != 0) {
        converted_number = converted_number * 10 + transform((temp_number % 10) * Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(base), i), Double.parseDouble(base));
        temp_number = temp_number / 10;
        i = i + 1;
    }
    return converted_number.toString();
}}
```

So for example when i call the function when the application starts, it crash.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Conversion conver = new Conversion();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Context c = this;
    AlertDialog.Builder m = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
    m.setMessage(conver.substitution("10", "10"));
    AlertDialog a = m.create();
    a.show();
```

Edit: I fix the crash problem, now my function returns "NaN"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out that the algorithm didn't worked out because that `while` loop stoped only when the double value reached out his lower point. So i fixed it up with `Math.floor()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have `Double.parseDouble("base")` in your code, remove double quotes

Comment: i removed that double quotes, now when i call `conver.substituion("10, "10")` it returns me "NaN"